# Transaction Management in nodejs with mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am working on nodejs with **MySQL**. I need to implement **transaction management** while inserting data in to multiple tables. So that I can **rollback** all insertions if any error occur.

All DB related operations are declared in different classes of each entity in DB layer. In business logic layer on a single operation we may need to handle multiple db layer calls from different entity. In JAVA Spring We can simply *annotate* **@Transaction** on service layer.

Is there anything like this in nodejs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NodeJs mysql has very well transaction management but not exactly similar to Spring.
But concept is similar -

1. Create db connection
2. connect to db use `connect`
3. Start the transaction using `beginTransaction`
4. execute transactional queries
5. If any query fails use `rollback`. This will abort the transaction.
6. if all goes well use `commit`
7. close the connection use `end`

An example -

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');
 
const connection = mysql.createConnection(
    {
      host     : 'YOUR_HOST',
      user     : 'YOUR_USERNAME',
      password : 'YOUR_PASSWORD',
      database : 'YOUR_DB_NAME'
    }
);
 
connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }
  console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});
 
/* Begin transaction */
connection.beginTransaction(function(err) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  connection.query('YOUR QUERY', "PLACE HOLDER VALUES", function(err, result) {
    if (err) { 
      connection.rollback(function() {
        throw err;
      });
    }
 
    const log = result.insertId;
 
    connection.query('ANOTHER QUERY PART OF TRANSACTION', log, function(err, result) {
      if (err) { 
        connection.rollback(function() {
          throw err;
        });
      }  
      connection.commit(function(err) {
        if (err) { 
          connection.rollback(function() {
            throw err;
          });
        }
        console.log('Transaction Completed Successfully.');
        connection.end();
      });
    });
  });
});
/* End transaction */
```

In case you want to make it more dynamic, just an idea. I have added some comments in code. You may have to change the code to suit to your requirement.
Basically you pass an array of queries along with query values and then all of them run in a transaction.
 -

```js
function executeTransaction(queries) {
    try {
      const connection = yield getConnectionObj({/* your db params to get connection */)
  
      let results = []

      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        connection.beginTransaction(function (err) {
          if (err) throw err

          console.log("Starting transaction")

          queries
            .reduce(function (sequence, queryToRun) {
              return sequence.then(function () {
                /* pass your query and connection to a helper function and execute query there */
                return queryConnection(
                  connection,
                  query,
                  queryParams,
                ).then(function (res) {
                  /* Accumulate resposes of all queries */
                  results = results.concat(res)
                })
              }).catch(function (error) {
                reject(error)
              })
            }, Promise.resolve())
            .then(function () {
              connection.commit(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                  connection.rollback(function () {
                    throw err
                  })
                }
                console.log('Transactions were completed!')
                /* release connection */
                connection.release()
                /* resolve promise with all results */
                resolve({ results })
              })
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
              console.log('Transaction failed!')
              connection.rollback(function () {
                console.log('Abort Transaction !!!')
                throw err
              })
            })
        })
      })
   /* End Transaction */

    } catch (error) {
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
  }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I implemented it the same way you provided in the example, but for a reason it doesn't `rollback` , The first query is executed even if the second query failed, might be something should be related to configuration in the `mysql database`?  The database type i am using is `innoDB`. I have been stuck on this since days. I have already opened a question. I appreciate your help there. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61593344/nodejs-mysql-transactions-not-working-as-expected?noredirect=1#comment108965652_61593344

Answer (score 1):

Coming from a java background, you may want to take a look at `sequelize` and `zb-sequelize`.

- Sequelize is a layer which acts like a driver to connect to many different SQL-based databases.
- [ZB-sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zb-sequelize) is an extension to sequelize which adds the `@Transactional` decorator.

It simplifies transaction management to a point where you don't have to create, commit or rollback transactions at all. All of that is taken care of by those 2 decorators.

```
import { Transactional, Tx } from 'zb-sequelize';

@Transactional
function fooBar(@Tx transaction) {
  foo(transaction);
  bar(transaction);
}
```

If you've worked with Spring before, then this will certainly look familiar.