# NodeJS - MySQL Transactions not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, transactions, rollback

I am trying to apply Trasnactions (`beginTransaction`,`rollback` and `commit`. however if the query of adding invoice (Frst Query) executed successfully I want to update the supplier amount (Second Query). I intended to write wrong syntax in the second query by changing `UPDATE` to `UPDATEEE`.  I assumed this should `rollback`. I got query syntax error message but the invoice added (first query successfully executed).

What is the wrong thing i am doing?

```
Invoice.addNewInvoice = function (invoice_data,result){

    sql.beginTransaction(function(err){
        if (err) { throw err; }

        sql.query('INSERT INTO invoice SET ?',invoice_data, function(err,res){
            if(err){
                sql.rollback(function() {
                    throw err;
                });
            }else{
                sql.query('UPDATEEEEE supplier SET supplier_amount = supplier_amount + ' + invoice_data.invoice_amount + ' WHERE supplier_id = ' + invoice_data.supplier_id, function(err,res){
                    if(err){
                        sql.rollback(function() {
                            throw err;
                        });
                    }
                })
                sql.commit(function(err) {
                    if (err) { 
                        sql.rollback(function() {
                            throw err;
                        });
                    }else{

                        result(null,res);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you turn off autocommit in your connection to MySQL?

Comment: @DaveD I tried to `set autocommit = 0'  it shows that it turned off, i even ensure it by `SELECT @@autocommit` the result was `0` but this doesn't change anything. do you have any thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that i set the `commit` to be executed even if the second query faild. it should be set on the `else` as below:

```
Invoice.addNewInvoice = function (invoice_data,result){

    sql.beginTransaction(function(err){
        if (err) { throw err; }

        sql.query('INSERT INTO invoice SET ?',invoice_data, function(err,res){
            if(err){
                sql.rollback(function() {
                    throw err;
                });
            }else{
                sql.query('UPDATEEEEE supplier SET supplier_amount = supplier_amount + ' + invoice_data.invoice_amount + ' WHERE supplier_id = ' + invoice_data.supplier_id, function(err,res){
                    if(err){
                        sql.rollback(function() {
                            throw err;
                        });
                    }else{
                        sql.commit(function(err) {
                            if (err) { 
                                sql.rollback(function() {
                                    throw err;
                                });
                            }else{

                                result(null,res);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })

            }

        });
    });
}
```

This way it rollback since if the second query faild.